# Bijection between sets with bounded difference.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does there exist a bijection between the set of integers and the set of even integers if the absolute value of the difference between any two "paired" numbers cannot exceed one billion?

I know that there's a bijection between the integers and the evens without the extra condition; simply pair every integer in the first set with twice its value in the second.

However this method will eventually cause too large a difference between values. 1,000,000,001 is paired with 2,000,000,002, which differ by more than 1,000,000,000. In fact, for any $\epsilon$, $\epsilon+1$ is paired with $2\epsilon+2$, which differ by more than $\epsilon$, so the proposed procedure breaks down. Is there an alternative bijection that satisfies this bounding condition? If not, can you prove that no valid functions exist? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there doesn't.

Let's try with 4 instead of one billion first.

Lets suppose that each of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 has an even image distant from it by at most 4. Then those images cannot be greater than 11. But between 0 and 11, there are only 6 even numbers. So, two of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 have the same image.

For the one billion case, consider the numbers 1, 2, ..., one billion + 3.

Comment: Thanks. It seems so obvious now that you explain it.